# XNA: Does the position of mouseState matter?

Tags: xna, c#

In order to get a single click response from MouseState, I use this line.

```
currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
```

And at the end of the method I have this line which sets the mouse state.

```
oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
```

My question to you is does the position of the above line matter in a method which has multiple loops? Is this:

```
            foreach (blah blah in blahs)
        {
            if (something is something)
            {
                if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    do something
                }
            }
        }oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
```

Different from this?

```
            foreach (blah blah in blahs)
        {
            if (something is something)
            {
                if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    do something
                }
            }oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
        }
```

Comment: Surely you could have investigated the outcome of your question by simply running your code.  Seems very obvious to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you have your mouseState update outside the FOREACH loop.  This makes everything in the FOREACH loop execute before the mouseState updates.

In your second example, you update the mouseState inside of your FOREACH loop, which is strange, but if you did, after the first looped item, the second if statement would fail and you would not "do something".